# How to map SQL multiple result sets to a C# View Model class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want map multiple sql statement with model c# 
 `var results = Database.SqlQuery<MemberStatsByTopCountryViewModel>("exec sp_members").ToList();`

```
 public class MemberStatsByTopCountryViewModel
{
    public int total { get; set; }
     public List<ContinentByPercentage> continentByPercentage { get; set; }
    public List<CountryByMembers> countrybyMembers { get; set; }

}
```

My sql statements below

[image]

Comment: It is of course very strange to see a ViewModel in a query. SOLID says you should separate your concerns better here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following one. That you need is to read multiple result sets.

```
// It's quite possible that the following line should be change.
// You should replace DbContext with your corresponding class. 
var db = new DbContext();

using(var connection = db.DataBase.Connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "EXEC your stored procedure name";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var total = reader.GetInt32(0);

        reader.NextResult();

        var continentByPercentage =((IObjectContextAdapter) db)
                            .ObjectContext
                            .Translate<ContinentByPercentage>(reader)
                            .ToList();

        reader.NextResult();

        var countrybyMembers =
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter) db)
                            .ObjectContext
                            .Translate<CountryByMembers>(reader)
                            .ToList();

        return new MemberStatsByTopCountryViewModel
        {
            total = total,
            continentByPercentage = continentByPercentage ,
            countrybyMembers = countrybyMembers 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: i need solution EF Database.SqlQuery mapping sql object to c# model

Comment: Using Database.SqlQuery with a custom object won't be able to properly assign your different result sets. Christos showed a good example here of how to map each result with your object.

Comment: Like the man says... you may need an EF solution but you cannot have one. This answer will help you.

Comment: @Christos i have similar scenario , but i am unable to get total

Comment: @RazimKhan It would be nice, if you write a question with a clear description of your case and the problem you phase. Otherwise, it is quite difficult for anyone to understand why you are unable to get the total. If you do so (write the question), please share here the link. Thanks

Comment: @Christos i have post the following post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61839217/get-multiple-result-set-with-store-procedure-using-entity-framework-calculated-c