# Get multiple result set with stored procedure using Entity Framework calculated column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, multiple-resultsets

I want to get multiple result sets from a stored procedure using Entity Framework. Result of table get successfully, but when I want to get a `Balance` column, it could not, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
public ViewModel GetTwoResultSetsForUserId(string Date, string FromDate, string ToDate, int userId)
{
    using (var db = new CuumiEntities())
    {
        // Create a SQL command and add parameter
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "getTransactionDatewisetesting";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", Date));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FromDate", FromDate));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ToDate", ToDate));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId));

        // execute your command
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        double Balance = reader.GetDouble(0);

        var transactions = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                                .ObjectContext
                                .Translate<transaction>(reader)
                                .ToList();

        reader.NextResult();

        var Expenses = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<spendingClass>(reader, "spendings", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();

        var balance = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<PrevBalance>(reader);

        return new ViewModel
               {
                   transactions = transactions,
                   Expenses = Expenses,
                   Balance = Balance
                };
    }
}
```

Here is my model which I want to return

[image]

and here is my stored procedure result:

[image]

Comment: Please, share what error you are getting, then it would be much easier for us to help you. I am guessing that you are getting an error on the line `double Balance = reader.GetDouble(0);`. You missed to read data before getting it. Try your code with addition as `if (reader.Read())
            {
                var Balance = reader.GetDecimal(0);
            }`.

Comment: @Nazim i get the following error on this line Specified cast is not valid
in sql server its type is decial and i am getting here in double

Comment: Types are different on SQL and C# side. In your case, if you want to read Balance as `double` type, do this update on your stored procedure to return Balance as FLOAT SQL Type. You can do something like `SELECT CAST(Balance AS FLOAT)`, then you can read result with `GetDouble(0)`. Alternatively, if it doesn't matter to be decimal or double change your code only and instead of `GetDouble(0)` use `GetDecimal(0)`.

Comment: @Nazim thanks. problem resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server and the .NET Framework are based on different type systems, that is why while reading data on .NET side you need to use data mapping carefully.

Here you can find list of type mapping or type equivalents between SQL Server and .NET Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

In your question, it wasn't clear what was the type of `Balance` column on SQL side or what type was coming from your stored procedure. In your code, you are trying to read `Balance` column as `Double`, that is where you are getting `Specified cast is not valid in sql server`. According to Microsoft's document(link shared above), it is stated that column type must be `Float` on SQL Server side so that on .NET side you can read it as `Double` type.

As you are getting type cast error, I guess you are returning non `Float` value from database. As a solution, you can update your stored procedure to cast your `Balance` to `Float` type.

Sample usage: `SELECT CAST(Balance AS FLOAT)`

Finally, just as a suggestion, wrap your `Connection` and `Reader` objects with `using` statement so that at the end of your execution, they are disposed, not to leave open connections, which eventually can result in all pooled connections are in use exception.